# document.querySelector("html").scrollTop returns zero even if the view is not at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I want to scroll the page when user clicks up/down arrow keys. `document.querySelector("html").scrollTop` returns `0` even if the page view is not completely at the top. This is on chrome browser,.

Are there any other ways to get the accurate current height position of the page?

Comment: You need to get the [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) of the element which can be scrolled. I assume in your case it is `document.body`.

Comment: Might consider using [`document.scrollingElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/scrollingElement).

Answer (score 0):

Check css property of HTML. if it's property is `overflow: hidden`, then it will not work.

Try scrolling in another element such as `body`, `div` etc.

```js
let scrollTopBtn = document.getElementById("scrollTop");
let scrollBottomBtn = document.getElementById("scrollBottom");

let scrollDiv = document.querySelector(".scrollable-div");

function scrollTo(elem, scrollValue) {
  elem.scrollTop += scrollValue;
}

scrollTopBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  scrollTo(scrollDiv, -35);
});

scrollBottomBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  scrollTo(scrollDiv, 35);
});
```

```css
div.scrollable-div{
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #222;
  overflow: scroll; /*important for scrolling*/
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
button{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button id="scrollTop">Scroll Top</button>
<button id="scrollBottom">Scroll Bottom</button>

<div class="scrollable-div">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

Hope this helps!
```